# load element content from external server

Tags: php, jquery

I am building my site base on the product data provided by the vendor. All product related pages are sitting on the vendor's site.

The vendor allows me to create a "product summary" link to use it as a post in Wordpress. Basically the post contains a list of products with brief infomation.

If I click on one of the products, it will take me to the "product detail" page which again it sits on the vendor's server.

At this point all I can do is show the "product summary" post as a teaser on my front page.

What I really want to use as a teaser on the front page is a few products instead of product summary.

I used file_get_contents() to echo the product detail on my "detail" post:

```
function demo_file_get_contents(){
    if(is_page('detail')){
       echo file_get_contents('http://vendorsite.com/product.html');
    }
}
add_action('wp_head','demo_file_get_contents');
```

Then I tried to capture the "green color" attribute, so I can assign this product to a "green" category and show the product as a group of green colored products teasers on the front page.

```
function demo_retriveAttr(){
  if(is_page('detail')){
     ?>            
        <script type="text/javascript">                
          jQuery(document).ready(function() {   
            $('#color').load('http://mysite.com/detail.html #product-color');            
          });
        </script>
      <?php
  }
}
add_action('wp_footer','demo_retriveAttr');
```

My questions are:

1. Is file_get_contents the best practice to capture external data?
2. the .load() function didn't work, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Quick Answers

1. The `file_get_contents` is a good one, if your server has access to the website.
2. If the `.load()` function didn't work, you might have to enable CORS. Cross Domain requests are generally blocked by the browser for safety.

Comment: I would add at least basic error checking for results of `file_get_contents`, unless an error message or blank string is considered a valid reply.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The file_get_contents was able to show the data on my own server. When I used the .load()function, I thought I was trying to access the local file I just retrieved so it shouldn't have cross domain issue.

Comment: Local to server or local to client? Should be on same domain. Not a local file, where only the server can access it!

Comment: It looks like I have some fundamental lessons to learn here! I thought file_get_contents() copies the page from external server and pastes it to my local server, then I can manipulate it. I knew .load() function has same origin policy so I used file_get_contents() first, I need to find a way to get the "color" attribute if .load() is not a good option.

Answer (score 1):

1. Alternative to file_get_contents(), you can also use the cURL method (ref. ["Download a URL’s Content Using PHP cURL"](http://davidwalsh.name/curl-download)). As far as best practice, I believe either method is appropriate. There is some good information about performance differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555523/file-get-contents-vs-curl-what-has-better-performance).
2. There are any number of reasons your .load() function might not be working. Have you checked the console for any error messages? Is there a reason you've decided to load the external server page content using the wp_head() hook? If file_get_contents() is pulling additional [html], [head] and [body] tags there are mostly conflicts from having multiple of the aforementioned tags in the same document.

Can you provide some code for the detail.html document? Specifically, where you're rocking the #product-color .

Comment: I don't have specific reason to use "wp_head" or "wp_footer" hooks, as I was just trying to demonstrate the issues. I used .load() function simply because as a newbie I copied from another post on this site and this function allows me to load content from a <div> tag element. I didn't get any error message, the "#color" <div> tag is still empty after running the .load() function.

Comment: Do you know if file_get_contents() is loading in the `<html>, <head>, and <body>` tags? If so, you're jQuery is most likely breaking, and this is why you're load() function is not working. Also, because you're a bit new to all of this, might I ask if you know how to use your browser's console window for debugging jQuery issues?

Comment: The answer is no, I am very new to this. All I am trying to figure out is what's the best way to display individual products as teasers on my front page where I can use shortcodes to display the data provided by the vendor. I am scratching my head at this moment!